# Elsarticle footnoting the addresses

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, elsarticle, addresses

Consider this example of an `elsarticle` template:

```
\documentclass[3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\journal{Nuclear Physics B}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Sample article to present \texttt{elsarticle} class\tnoteref{label0}}
\tnotetext[label0]{This is only an example}


\author[label1,label2]{Author One\corref{cor1}\fnref{label3}}
\address[label1]{Address One}
\address[label2]{Address Two\fnref{label4}}

\cortext[cor1]{I am corresponding author}
\fntext[label3]{I also want to inform about\ldots}
\fntext[label4]{Small city}

\ead{author.one@mail.com}
\ead[url]{author-one-homepage.com}

\author[label5]{Author Two}
\address[label5]{Some University}
\ead{author.two@mail.com}

\author[label1,label5]{Author Three}
\ead{author.three@mail.com}

\begin{abstract}
    Text of abstract. Text of abstract. Text of abstract. Text of abstract. Text of abstract. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    example \sep \LaTeX \sep template
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

where the footnote superscripts are not shown:

> [image]

I tried replacing `fnref` with `footnote` now it shows the annotation, how ever it keeps incrementing even when referring to the same footnote! for example changing the below lines:

```
\address[label2]{Address Two\footnote{label4}}
\address[label5]{Some University\footnote{label4}}
```

yields:

> [image]
>
> [image]

which is obviously wrong. I would appreciate if you could help me know how I can fix this.

**P.S.** [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/a3odk8/elsarticle_footnoting_the_addresses/) to the Reddit post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a workaround. Basically one can specify the footnote mark with `\footnote[label]{tag}` so if I change the above lines to:

```
\address[label2]{Address Two\footnote[2]{label4}}
\address[label5]{Some University\footnote[2]{label4}}
```

the issue is resolved:

> [image]

and whenever that doesn't work a fast and dirty workaround is to just superscript the numbers with `\textsuperscript{2}`

Comment: For me this prints the footnote twice at the bottom.